# Ограничить обращение к базе при использовании unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у меня есть вот такой вот метод какого-нибудь класса:

```
def sum(self):
    var1 = value1_from_database()
    var2 = value2_from_database()
    return var1 + var2
```

**Как я могу потом в юнит-тесте подменить обращение к базе чем-нибудь своим ?**

Например, чтобы получилось что-то вроде этого, но только с дублерами:

```
def test_sum(self):
    super_alpha_object.var1 = 3
    super_alpha_object.var2 = 4
    self.assertEqual(super_alpha_object.sum(), 7)
```